# Permission denied message on Android method tracing

Tags: android

I'm trying to follow these steps to help figure out where my first Android app (using Android Studio, targeting a Nexus 9) is crashing:

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

I added `Debug.startMethodTracing` and `Debug.stopMethodTracing` to my main activity code in the recommended places.  When I actually debug my code I get the following message in my "logcat" window.

```
02-17 11:40:34.418  15711-15711/com.mpr.myfirstapp E/art﹕ Unable to open trace file '/storage/emulated/legacy/seemore.trace': Permission denied
```

I'm not sure why this is, and I'm also not sure how in Android Studio to view the trace logs.  Can anyone help?

NOTE:
It seems worth noting that (from the link)

> Android 2.2 and later devices do not need an SD card. The trace log
>   files are streamed directly to your development machine.

So I'm not sure if the permission issue is on my dev machine or on the device.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Android Device Monitor to trace from your dev machine.

Try adding these to your AndroidManifest.xml and let me know if the error is still there.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then in terminal you want to run (if you're on PC the command would be different but similar)

```
adb pull /sdcard/seemore.trace ~/tmp
```

Then open up Android Device Monitor and open up the file, now located in

```
~/tmp/seemore.trace
```

you can start the Android Device Monitor using the command

```
./monitor
```

Comment: That all seemed to work straight away, thanks!  However my trace file is surprisingly zero length.  My app crashes pretty quick but I thought the trace would tell me which method is crashing.  Does this suggest that my app is crashing before any tracing occurs, or is it more likely I'm not tracing properly?

Comment: @Chris Hm. I'm not sure how the Debug.startMethodTracing method works but it's possible it's crashing immediately after that and thus not writing anything... are you not getting ANY stack trace in the ide? Put in some breakpoints in your app and run it in debug mode.